# binding and currying in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand binding and currying. Can someone please provide an example of how to create a new url?

```
var paths = [apath, bpath];    

function simpleURL(protocol, domain, path) {
    return protocol + "://" + domain + "/" + path;
}

var urls = paths.map(simpleURL.bind(null, "http", siteDomain));
```

Comment: `urls` in your example is not a function, it's an array. You cannot call it.

Comment: also, this isn't currying, this is partial application.

Comment: `simpleURL.bind` already does the "binding and currying" for you. `urls` is just an array of strings

Comment: Thanks,  how do I create a new URL for each path? I assume sitedomain needs to change for each iteration?

Comment: New _function_ or a new _string_? And `I assume sitedomain needs to change for each iteration` - how would we know?

Comment: `simpleURL.bind(null, "http", siteDomain)` returns a new simpleURL in a way, it's already fulfilled with the first two params of simpleURL (the first parameter to bind is the intended `this`). `map` calls this function with 'apath' and another time with 'bpath'.